# Capture Masstransit information when using prometheus pushgateway

Tags: c#, .net-core, prometheus, masstransit

MassTransit supports Prometheus metric capture, which provides useful observability into the bus, endpoints, consumers, and messages when using the below code in asp.net core application.

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.UsePrometheusMetrics(serviceName: "order_service");
        });
    });
```

and

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
    app.UseMetricServer();
}
```

In our case, we would like to use prometheus pushgateway to push the metrics in .NET Core console app (not ASP.NET Core). After using the below code, we are getting the basic metrics (dotnet total memory, process cpu seconds, etc.). Is there any way to get masstransit endpoint, consumer, etc. details?

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.UsePrometheusMetrics(serviceName: "order_service");
        });
    });
```

and

```
var pusher = new MetricPusher(new MetricPusherOptions
{
    Endpoint = "https://pushgateway.example.org:9091/metrics",
    Job = "some_job"
});

pusher.Start();
```

Comment: From the prometheus-net docs it looks like you should get your metrics pushed. If you look at the service metrics endpoint (HTTP GET), do you see all the metrics coming up in the response>

Comment: Thanks @Alexeyzimarev. Found the issue, the push has to be done after completing the process instead of pushing at the beginning stage.